# Should you unplug the cable once your MBP is fully charged?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

With Mavericks is this still needed? Doesn't this eventually cause the battery to die faster because it means it'll have to go through more cycles frequently?

Answer (score 1):

Personally if I am using the machine I will keep the charger plugged in until I'm done, regardless of whether its full or not, if I'm not using the machine I will unplug when its full.

Read up on Apple's official recommendations, there is some good stuff here:

http://www.apple.com/batteries/

Follow the links at the bottom.